# Custom policy preventing site template creation

Tags: infopath, site-template, information-management

If I apply a custom policy to a Document Library, I can no longer save that site as a template - any ideas why?

Incase it's relevant, I'm defining a label "Version: {Version}" which I later use to display the SP version number in a Word Doc (via Quick parts)

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in SP 2010 RTM. It is now possible since the October 2010 CU, however you may still find problems.

[Some users have reported](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/51abcb32-8aba-477f-9739-2e674612f294/) that the document library and/or policy settings in saved templates are corrupt when using the October and December 2010 CUs.